# How to Export only one column after a SQL Selection

Tags: sql, select, export

I am using a specific SQL query to make a selection in a database.
(such query is related to two tables, where the common column is id_product)
The query returns 2 columns.
As the content of column 2 is rather heavy, I would like to export only column 1, as a CSV file (the column 1 is id_product)

I did not find how to do it.

Would you know how to export only one column after a sql selection ?

I thank you in advance for any reply.

Patrick

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using? What research have you done?

Comment: My initial SQL query was as follows :

SELECT t2.id_product, t2.description from ps_product_lang t2
inner join ps_product t1 on t1.id_product = t2.id_product
where t2.description LIKE '%a specific string%'
AND t2.id_lang = 2
AND t1.active = 1.

Such query returns two columns :
id_product and description.

Is there a way to amend such query in order to return only one column : id_product.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You still haven't told us your SQL dialect.

Comment: I made the query in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

U need to use T-SQL. Also u need to:

- You need to have the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
- The .CSV file have be already exist .

Sample code:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [FileName.csv]')
    --Your Select statement---
    SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM DatabaseName
```